# mySql Trigger for Order

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
stock (id, Quantity, Date,product_id);

orderdetails (Details_id, Order_Id, Product_id, qty, price);
```

I need to create a trigger to update the stock (Quantity, Date) every time a new Transaction is made.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_cut_stock_insert
    before insert ON orderdetails
    FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
   Update stock set Quantity = qty - Quantity where pid = @pid;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What's is problem here? Your missing the question.

Comment: i want to get the exact trigger to update stock quantity every new transcation purchase

Comment: What isn't working? You do not have a clear question in your post. Edit your post and explain what isn't working, or how your code isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: You should also add another trigger on before update in case the quantity is changed.

Comment: Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger..in an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html